# Window Always on top is not working when any other app is on full screen

Tags: electron, always-on-top

Electron Version

23.1.0

What operating system are you using?

macOS

Operating System Version

Mac M1 Pro

What arch are you using?

Other (specify below)

Last Known Working Electron version

11.0.0

Expected Behavior

I am using code this way :

```
mainWindow.setVisibleOnAllWorkspaces(true, { visibleOnFullScreen: true });
mainWindow.setAlwaysOnTop(true, 'floating', Number.MAX_VALUE);
mainWindow.setFullScreenable(false);
```

App should be always on the top for all the applications.

Actual Behavior

App is currently on the top usually but any time any other application like Chrome, Zoom or any other app gets into full screen mode my electron app is no longer always on top.

Electron Version

23.1.0

What operating system are you using?

macOS

Operating System Version

Mac M1 Pro

What arch are you using?

Other (specify below)

Last Known Working Electron version

11.0.0

Expected Behavior

I am using code this way :

```
mainWindow.setVisibleOnAllWorkspaces(true, { visibleOnFullScreen: true });
mainWindow.setAlwaysOnTop(true, 'floating', Number.MAX_VALUE);
mainWindow.setFullScreenable(false);
```

App should be always on the top for all the applications.

Actual Behavior

App is currently on the top usually but any time any other application like Chrome, Zoom or any other app gets into full screen mode my electron app is no longer always on top.

Comment: If it used to work, I'm guessing this is an Electron bug. Does [this help](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/35299)?